# Magento 2: Add new attribute not showing in list

Tags: magento2, product, configurable-product

I've created new product and clicked Create Configurations at the bottom of the product page. I then clicked 'Create New Attribute', added a name for it and then a code. Once saved, I'm taken back to the Create Configurations page but my new attribut isn't listed, just the usual three (color, size and format).

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to assign your new attributes to the attribute group. Go to `store->products`(Under Attribute label). Then drag your new attribute to the attribute group.

For more details about creating attribute check this link https://www.fastcomet.com/tutorials/magento2/product-attributes

Comment: Welcome to community! Happy learning

Answer (score 0):

The attribute must also be set to a "global" scope.

Answer (score 0):

The attribute must also be "required" to be used for a Configurable product.